# javascript nested object and arrays adding new element problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

here is my code piece

```
let users2 = [
    {
        _id: 'ab12ex',
        username: 'Alex',
        email: 'alex@alex.com',
        password: '123123',
        createdAt:'08/01/2020 9:00 AM',
        isLoggedIn: false
    },
    {
        _id: 'fg12cy',
        username: 'Asab',
        email: 'asab@asab.com',
        password: '123456',
        createdAt:'08/01/2020 9:30 AM',
        isLoggedIn: true
    },
    {
        _id: 'zwf8md',
        username: 'Brook',
        email: 'brook@brook.com',
        password: '123111',
        createdAt:'08/01/2020 9:45 AM',
        isLoggedIn: true
    },
    {
        _id: 'eefamr',
        username: 'Martha',
        email: 'martha@martha.com',
        password: '123222',
        createdAt:'08/01/2020 9:50 AM',
        isLoggedIn: false
    },
    {
        _id: 'ghderc',
        username: 'Thomas',
        email: 'thomas@thomas.com',
        password: '123333',
        createdAt:'08/01/2020 10:00 AM',
        isLoggedIn: false
    }
    ];

const date = new Date()
let exactTime = date.toLocaleString('en-KL', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })

const signUp = (username,email,password,isLoggedIn) => {
    let obj = {
        _id: 'ddfcd',
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        createdAt:`${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth()}/${date.getFullYear()} ${exactTime}`,
        isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
    }
    let arr = [`${users2.length}`, obj]
    let collection = Object.entries(users2)
    collection.push(arr)
    users2 = collection
}

signUp('ali','ali@mail.com','123',false)
signUp('kerem','kerem@protonmail.com','456',false)
signUp('johndoe','jd@jd.com','789',true)
```

when i get new user data at first the new one is exacrly similar with the rest however when add second one (or more) it misses an array it just turns array into object

[here is the example what i mean when i add one more user then the previous one gets normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFA9X.png)

what's the problem here

Comment: Why are you using `Object.entries` on `users2`? what IS users2?

Comment: sorry forgot to add data

Comment: so, why are you using `Object.entries` on users2? all you need to do is push the new user onto `users2` - i.e. `users2.push(obj)` is the ONLY line needed after `obj` is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have overcomplicated pushing an object to an Array

All you want to do is push to `users2`

```
const signUp = (username,email,password,isLoggedIn) => {
    users2.push({
        _id: 'ddfcd',
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        createdAt:`${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth()}/${date.getFullYear()} ${exactTime}`,
        isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
    });
}
```